# How can i record in game/app/or whatever that is occurring from your phone instead of recording through mic?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

i trying to record audio that is coming from the phone instead of using the mic, using MediaRecorder of course. Now i see there is a method that allows me to set the audio source, `mediaRecorder.setAudioSource()`. And it has constants that i can use such as Camcorder, Mic, Default and so on. I wonder if default allows me to record whatever that is playing in the phone system? Or is there another way? Whatever that may help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is full code audio recording and save file in memory

```
 public class AudioRecord extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        Button play, stop, record;
        //private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
        //private String outputFile = null;
         File audiofile = null;
        //MediaRecorder recorder = null;
        Uri fileUri = null;

        Chronometer myChronometer;
        private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
        //private static String mFileName = null;
        private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.record_audio);
            myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
            stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
            record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);

            stop.setEnabled(false);
            play.setEnabled(false);
            long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            try {
                audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound"+current, ".3gp", sampleDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("AAA", "sdcard access error");
                return;
            }
            record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    myChronometer.start();
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

                    try
                    {
                        mRecorder.prepare();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                    }

                    mRecorder.start();


                    record.setEnabled(false);
                    stop.setEnabled(true);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;

                    stop.setEnabled(false);
                    play.setEnabled(true);
                    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    myChronometer.stop();
                    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                }
            });

            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException
                {
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                  //  data.putExtra("result",mFileName);
                    data.setData(fileUri);
                    //data.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName)));
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

                    finish();
                    //  startPlaying();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
            long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

            Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
            M.L("Added File " + newUri);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fileUri=newUri;
        }


// Record audio XML 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#050505"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mix_record"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Recoding... "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"

                android:textSize="60sp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#171A1D"
            android:src="@drawable/a_microphone"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#9b9b9b"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRecord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:text="Record"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Stop"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:text="send"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not answer my question. I know there is a full code and what not, what i am asking is how can i record the audio in my phone instead of recording through the mic. Such as recording the screen activity, recording a gameplay on the screen. Something simpler, just the audio that is playing in the phone.